# Approximation with null derivative test functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, distribution-theory

Assume one has the function $g(x)=f(x)1_{[a,b]}(x)$ with $f\in C(\mathbb{R})$. Can one finds a sequence of test functions $\psi_n\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ such that

$$\psi_n\rightarrow g, \;\;\;\;\; with \; \; \; \; \; \psi_n'=0.$$

Comment: The only test function satisfying $\psi'=0$ is $\psi(x)\equiv 0.$ Are you asking for piecewise constant test functions?

Comment: I was thinking of a mollification  of piecewise constant. Want to have better ideas

Answer (score 1):

The function $g$ can be approximated with piecewise constant functions $\gamma_n$.

Take a mollifier $\rho_n$ and set $\psi_n=\gamma_n*\rho_n.$ Then $\psi_n \to g*\delta=g.$

Comment: But $\psi_n'\neq 0$...

Comment: @stochastic_name_here. Could you draw a graph of an example $\psi_n$?

Comment: It is an histogram with smoothed edges. The derivative is not a.e. 0 as long as the interval of a single smoothed edge for example has non zero measure, also depending on n.

Comment: Take $\rho_n\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}),$ i.e. with compact support. Let it have support on a very short interval. Then $\psi_n$ will be just as you want it.

Comment: The very short interval will have for all $n$ non-zero measure. Rounding corners has the advantage of obtaining a smooth function and the disadvantage of enlarging the interval where the function is not anymore affine, i.e. with null derivative. That's the point. I think it can't be achieved. Just think about the graph of a usual mollified function like the one at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier.

Comment: I'm really confused of what you want. It seems like you want 1) $\psi_n\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R),$ 2) $\psi_n'\equiv 0$ and 3) $\psi\neq 0.$ Could you explain better what you want, perhaps with a graph?

Comment: 1)+(2) \mu a.e.) where \mu is Lebesgue. With the mollification 2) doesn’t hold \mu-a.e. because in an interval of non zero measure the derivative psi’_n is not 0. Can you see it now?

Comment: So you want to have steps **and** be smooth at the same time? That's impossible. If $\psi_n' \neq 0$ only $\mu$-a.e. then $\psi_n$ is piecewise constant and can not be in $C^\infty_c$ unless $\psi_n\equiv0.$